# Effective algorithm to remove image blur due to camera shake when shaking direction and magnitude are uniform

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graphics, motion-blur

I would like to know what algorithms are most effective in removing image blur due to camera shake. To simplify matters, I am interested in algorithms for RGB images where the direction of shaking and the magnitude are known (by measurement in terms of degrees and number of pixels respectively) and uniform throughout the image, just like the constructed example as shown in the image below (hence after applying the algorithm, ideally the sharp black A should be obtained):

[image]

The algorithm should take the number of degrees and number of pixels as input, just like the Remove Motion Blur option in the Smart Sharpen feature in Photoshop. Any idea will be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need this for real cameras? They can be modeled as a central projection. Hence, blur direction and magnitude change with the pixel's position.

Comment: look for motion deblurring (for example: http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/publications/pdfs/BenEzra_CVPR03.pdf)

Comment: A quick Google search reveals http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-do-i-remove-motion-blur, which has some good references. And https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/deblur_fergus.pdf looks promising. Really, you should do a little research before posting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidelines, I did have researched but the problem for me is that I didn't know the term to look for apart from "reduce camera shake". (Terms such as "Deconvolution" are really beyond me.) Wiener Filtering was the most promising I could find, but I tried a free software with Wiener Filtering and it did not work very as promising as I expected.